# Creating not-so-random list from given array in PHP

Tags: php, list, random

I need to generate list of *n* (`$size_of_list`) names...
Possible members are given in array (`$names_list`) which gives name and chances of appearance of that name. So it is an *array of 40 arrays of string and integer:*

```
$names_list = array (
                     0 => array ('name' => "Mike", 'frequency' => 8),
                     1 => array ('name' => "Jane", 'frequency' => 7),
                     2 => array ('name' => "Leopold", 'frequency' => 1),
                     3 => array ('name' => "George", 'frequency' => 5),
...
                     39 => array ('name' => "Mark", 'frequency' => 6)
                    )
```

`$names_list[0] = array('name' => "Mike", 'frequency' => 8)` means that $name="Mike" has $frequency (or chance) of 8, and "Leopold" has chance value 1 - small chance to appear...

Comment: My question would be how large is this array ever likely to get as if it is sizable possible solutions may run into memory limits, the other question is what is generating this array in the first instance? there may be a much smarter way to approach this issue

Comment: @Anigel size of input array `$names_list` is always 40 elements, but output can be as large as 5-6.000 elements... actually i have 5-6 more input arrays of which i need to generate test db of at least 4-5.000 elements...

Comment: @Anigel but i'll put generated values in db one by one so size wont matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify $size_of_list and check out $result in the end. This uses random depending on weight.

```
$result = array();

$total = 0;
foreach ($names_list as $row) {
    $total += $row['frequency'];
}

$max = mt_getrandmax();
$pre_sum = $total / $max;

for ($i = 0; $i < $size_of_list; ++$i) {

    $sum = $pre_sum * mt_rand(0, $max); // $sum = $total * (mt_rand(0, $max)/$max);

    foreach ($names_list as $row) {
        if (($sum -= $row['frequency']) < 0) {
            $result[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thanks, that was first thing i was planning to do, but didn't know how :)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to expand array with new value `'rnd'` which represents sum of `$frequency` and previous elements `rnd` (where first element 'rnd' is first element's 'frequency')

```
$names_list[0]['rnd'] = $names_list[0]['frequency'];
for ($i=1; $i<count($names_list); $i++)
    $names_list[$i]['rnd'] = $names_list[$i]['frequency'] + $names_list [$i-1]['rnd'];
```

and expanded array would look like this:

```
$names_list = array (
                     0 => array ('name' => "Mike", 'frequency' => 8, 'rnd' => 8),
                     1 => array ('name' => "Jane", 'frequency' => 7, 'rnd' => 15),
                     2 => array ('name' => "Leopold", 'frequency' => 1, 'rnd' => 16),
                     3 => array ('name' => "George", 'frequency' => 5, 'rnd' => 21),
//... other elements
                     39 => array ('name' => "Mark", 'frequency' => 8, 'rnd' => $sum_of_all_frequencies)
                    )
```

And then set $rand_max to value of last elements `'rnd'`, and then to create finale list by 
comparing `$random` and all `'rnd'` values...

```
$rand_max = $names_list[count($names_list)-1]['rnd'];

for ($i=1; $i<$size_of_list; $i++)
{
    $random = rand (1, $rand_max);
    $result = $names_list[0]['name'];
    foreach ($names_list as $key => $val)
        if ( ($random) > ($val['rnd']) )
            $result = $names_list[$key+1]['name'];

    $list[$i] = $result;
}
```

This solution works, but i think there are better (smarter) ways...
I would appreciate any help/suggestion...